# Как размывать все что сзади моего javaFX приложения

Tags: java, javafx

И вот, у меня есть этот код

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("login-form.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 720, 400, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.getRoot().getStylesheets().add(BootstrapFX.bootstrapFXStylesheet());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setTitle("Doxxsedds Loader");

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
```

он выводит это
[image: Что он выводит]
так вот, как мне сделать так чтобы все после этого окна размывалось

Comment: Не проверял, но гугл выдаёт такое https://github.com/kieferlam/JavaFX-Blur

Comment: @andreymal работает, но залагивает сразу

Comment: @andreymal получилось, восстановил.